# How we can make multiple syntax?

Tags: java

How we can make multiple counters? The first counter should count from 1 to 10 and the second counter should count from 4 to 20.

Is it possible (Using `For` or `While` methods)?

Comment: That makes no sense. `syntax` is not an object that can be manipulated. Do you mean `int`, or `object`?

Comment: int like this : for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
}

Comment: Downvotes without comment aren't helpful.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter's comment has already been commented by someone else. No need for dup comments

Comment: @Shredder - true, but the downvoter's comment didn't get any upvotes either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you mean the loops should be nested or sequential. Here's how to do nested loops using `for`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    for (int j = 4; j <= 20; ++j) {
        // do something with i and j
    }
}
```

The inner loop can, of course, also exist independently.

You can also do either or both loops using `while`:

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
    for (int j = 4; j <= 20; ++j) {
        // do something with i and j
    }
    ++i;
}
```

(The inner loop can also be changed to a `while` loop if you like.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
{
  for (int j = 4; j <= 20; j++)
  {
    // code goes here
  }
}
```